# SMTP DKIM for 1 add-on domain on 2 servers

Tags: centos, smtp, vps, dkim

Is there a more practical way for SMTP DKIM signing for a VPS server that has a parked domain but does not host the content other than private key copying?
I have looked all over Server Fault but could not find any exact reference to my situation. I'll try to explain as easy as possible:

2 servers (1 dedicated, 1 vps) both running cpanel 78, centos 7

Server 1 (dedicated) hostname is: server.myserver1.com (ns1/ns2.myserver1.com)
Server 1 has add-on domain that hosts content named: mywebsite.com
Created test@mywebsite.com and sent email via PHPMailer
DKIM, SPF, DMARC works fine no issues.

Server 2 (VPS) hostname is: server.myserver2.com (ns1/ns2.myisp.com)
Server 2 has parked domain that DOES NOT host content named: mywebsite.com
Created test@mywebsite.com and sent email via PHPMailer
SPF and DMARC works fine no issues; DKIM does not sign.

mywebsite.com is pointed to ns1/ns2.myserver.com (Server 1) at registrar

MY THEORY:
If I copy the private key from Server 1:  /var/cpanel/domain_keys/private/mywebsite.com then replace the private key on Server 2 with the private key from Sever 1 the smtp DKIM signing should validate.

Server 2 is simply configured as an SMTP server for mywebsite.com while Server 1 will still receive incoming emails for mywebsite.com since MX is pointed to Server 1 as well.

Any help would be appreciated I hope this makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a few things you can do to tell people no mail originates from the parked domain:

Using `example.com` for illustrations:

```
example.com           TXT   "v=spf1 -all"
_dmarc.example.com    TXT   "v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mail@example.com; ruf=mail@example.com"
```

If you also dont want mail sent to the parked domain then add:

```
example.com    MX    0    .
```

Note: destination hostname is just a dot, which means nobody handles mail for `example.com`